# How to deploy a web application to Azure Web App while signing the binaries?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, strongname, signtool

I have a solution with a web application that I want to deploy to Azure App Service. My solution contains assembly attributes to sign the assemblies using an installed key container (using `sn -i <infile> <container>`). This solution also builds an MSI file for the clients' usage, which is signed using `signtool`. Now I want to setup an automatic deployment for the web application in this solution to Azure App Service. I prefer to wire it up with GitHub instead of publishing the binaries elsewhere and using them to deploy.

When I connected my GitHub account, the deployment fails because it can't sign these binaries. I know I have to give my certificate for signing somehow, but don't know how. I was hoping I could use Azure Key Vault, but not sure how to wire it up with the build that gets triggered when a checkin in made. What is the best way to achieve automated deployment to Azure App Service.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Web Roles with Startup task in order to copy your assembly, however, I'll search if there's an option to keep with App Service for that.

Startup tasks with Web Roles: 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-startup-tasks/